# Images stretching in flex box IOS 15.7 only

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://jubileesquarestalbans.com/main/

I'm told all the photos on this site are stretching vertically on iPhone 15.7 IOS. They are fine on all current desktop browsers and on Android browsers. Also seems fine on the iPhone simulator in xCode.

An example is:

```
       <div class="content multi-pic">
           <div class="pic-grid c3 height-fill">
              <div class="column" style="width: 40%">
                 <img class="pic-base" src="./images/cathedral/cathedral1.jpg" alt="cathedral1">
              </div>
              <div class="column" style="width: 30%">
                 <img src="./images/cathedral/cath2.jpg" alt="cathedral2">
                 <img src="./images/cathedral/cath4.jpg" alt="cathedral4">
              </div>
              <div class="column" style="width: 30%">
                 <img src="./images/cathedral/cathedral3.jpg" alt="cathedral3">
                 <img src="./images/cathedral/cathedral5.jpg" alt="cathedral5">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.multi-pic {
    
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

.mob-stack {
    
    flex-direction: row;
    
}

.pic-grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.pic-grid.c2 .column {
    width: 50%;
}

.pic-grid.c3 .column {
    width: 33.3%;
    min-height:100%;
}

.pic-grid .column {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 var(--pic-padding);
}

.pic-grid .column:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.pic-grid .column:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.pic-grid .column img {
    padding-bottom: calc( var(--pic-padding) * 2 ); 
}

.pic-grid.height-fill .column img {
    flex: 1 auto;
}
```

I have tried align-items: center; and other values for this property but still it is stretching.

Comment: I just test the url with iOS 16 and it was fine both with safari and chrome.

Comment: Thanks, apparently it is iOS 15.7 on the client's iPhone but don't know why that would be a problem.

Comment: I seem to have it fixed with align-items: flex-start; on boxes with horizontal stacked images and width: 100% on boxes with vertical stacked images.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have it fixed with align-items: flex-start; on boxes with horizontal stacked images and width: 100% on boxes with vertical stacked images.